# xpath for select single with optional child (c#)

Tags: c#, xpath

is there a more concise/performant way to do the following with xpath 1.0?

```
 XPathNavigator navigator = ...;
 var node = navigator.SelectSingleNode(
                "./table[1]/tr[1]/td[1] | ./table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/a"
            );
```

Comment: that will return both `tr` and `a` if both exist

Comment: i removed my comment.  the code is self evident as to what it does.